# How to write trigger on the source table

Tags: plsql, triggers, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a table data_package_code with schema as follows:

```
Name              Null? Type         
----------------- ----- ------------ 

mult qty                VARCHAR2(2)  
CHARGE                  NUMBER(19,4) 
Credit Charge           NUMBER(19,4) 
Stop Date               VARCHAR2(7)  
Table_id                NUMBER       
SYS_CREATION_DATE       DATE
```

I want to implement a trigger which will run an insert statement on the same table to add `sysdate` in sys_creation_date column.

It is done to store the date on which a new entry is inserted in the table.

My implementation is as follows:

```
create or replace trigger package_insert_date
before insert on data_package_code for each row
begin
    insert into data_package_code(sys_creation_date)
    values(sysdate);
end;
```

But it is giving me an error on line 2.

I am using oracle sql developer for this project.

Answer (score 1):

It is just

```
create or replace trigger package_insert_date
  before insert on data_package_code 
  for each row
begin
  :new.sys_creation_date := sysdate;
end;
```

Although, you could have created table that way:

```
create table ...
  (...
   sys_creation_date   date   default sysdate     --> this
  );
```

Comment: Thanks and yes I should've done that.